# Background image not displaying on heroku flask deployment

Tags: html, css, heroku

**Summary:**
I have an html page that looks fine locally but when I deploy it to heroku a background image is missing.

**What I've tried:**
I'm currently using the property `background-image: url(bg.jpg);`

I've also tried `image-url(bg.jpg)` and `asset-url(bg.jpg)` (neither of these work locally).

**What I've read:**
From what I've read there are a few possibilities

- set `config.serve_static_assets = true`
- set `config.assets.compile = true`

I don't really understand how to set these? I keep seeing "*production.rb file*" referenced but I have no idea what this is? Can I set these properties from within heroku dashboard?

Currently I just push my code to GitHub and deploy from there. I'm new to Heroku and deployment in general, any help on this topic would be appreciated.

**procfile**

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

**file-structure**

```
procfile
requirements.txt
app.py
templates
  |- index.html
  |- positive.html
  |- negative.html
  |- bg.jpg
```

Comment: You need to provide code of your webserver. You are serving html, css files but there are webservers for any programming language and their implementation varies. Also a folder structure overview of your project is needed. Finally the command you use locally to run your project and on heroku the Procfile as well as other Heroku specific files.

Comment: Code of webserver?
I have an html file with a <style> tag for the css.
I don't use a command to run anything? It's a flask app though if that helps? I just open the .html file with my web-browser to see it locally.

Updated question for folder structure and Procfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this question. I realize now that because this is a Flask app that it needs to be handled differently.

The following change will correct the error: change the file structure to put the image in a static folder (Flask knows to look for this) and then change the url call.

**file-structure**

```
procfile
requirements.txt
app.py
static
  |- img
      |- bg.jpg
templates
  |- index.html
  |- positive.html
  |- negative.html
  |- bg.jpg
```

and

```
background-image: url('/static/img/bg.jpg');
```

I'm not sure why this resolves the problem but it works!